# Power BI - is it possible to Change "data source" for the Existing Report from "SQL-DB" to "PBI Dataset"?

Tags: powerbi

I have 3 existing reports
Report-1, Report-2, Report-3,
each with:

- connection to the same SQL-database ( "data source" )
- same set of queries, that are identical

Goal:

- for Report-2 and Report-3 to use dataset in Report-1, Without re-creating those 2 reports completely, but with mostly just changing data source.

---

I've tried:
1.
To connect Report-2 to Report-1-dataset with direct query
and
"DirectQuery to AS - ...." was added to the list of data sources for Report-2.

But old data source (SQL-DB) was Not removed, and it's Not possible to remove it.
And there is no errors of any kind.

And I do Not see columns that correspond to Report-1-dataset, meaning it is Not used still by Report-2.

2. I also tried:

   - Create a new import query using your MSSQL source   **-> NOT possible, there is No "Power BI Dataset" source to select ?**
   - Apply all necessary steps so that it resembles your Excel import table
   - Open that query in the Advanced editor and copy all lines
   - Open your Excel import table in the Advanced editor, delete all lines and paste in the lines from step 3
   - Since you don't change your original table name, all visuals will be preserved.

Is it possible to Change "data source" for the Existing Report from "SQL-DB" to "PBI Dataset" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Manually, you are going to have to start afresh with Report 2 and 3. However you can copy'n'paste visuals across for each page, then you'll need to add any Report/Page filters and any other tweaks.

Create a new PBIX, live connect to your dataset. Go to page 1 of Report 2, Select all visuals, and paste into the new report.

There is also this using PowerShell: https://powerbi.tips/2020/06/split-an-existing-power-bi-file-into-a-model-and-report/